# Implementing shapes that can be dynamically changed

Tags: android

Am I approaching this correctly or is there a better way?

I would like to have various shapes such as lines, rectangles, etc, that a user would be able to re-size, rotate, and otherwise change its parameters by clicking on the shape and dragging.

So far, I've implemented this with shapes by drawing the shape into a view and then adding the view onto a layout.  A user can then drag that view.

But is this the best way? By doing this, I am manipulating the view that contains the shape and not the shape itself.

Can the shape be re-sized/moved directly through user manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to draw shapes in Android is extend class from view then draw shapes in onDraw method also you can resize and move shapes using onTouch method dynamically.

Refer this link,
http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/

Comment: Wouldn't you be re-sizing and moving shapes using the view that they are contained in?  That's what I have already implemented.  I was wondering if the shapes can be manipulated directly.

Comment: this is ok to add view(custom shape) and move onTouch. but is it possible to resize and rotate onTouch event ?. Suppose on touch of view one new icon(say gripper) add on top-left corner of shape and when user drag this gripper the shape would resize according to that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.On selecting the shape you will get the selected point(Using any algorithm) and then redraw the shape.

Comment: nik431, can some kind of an actionListener be added to the shape or would I have to figure out whether a touch occurred within a shape by using the shape's location, etc?  This could get difficult for complex shapes.